# Regex not equal to multiple strings?

Tags: regex

Say the string not equal to `foo` nor `bar`. How to write the regex?

Comment: `^(?!(?:foo|bar)$)` or `^(?!(?:foo|bar)$).*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Although I don't understand it, it works.

Comment: Paste into http://regex101.com and read the explanation on the right.